# Transform a dataframe to a column for another.dataframe pandas PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge together two tables in particular way:

First one in.this way:

```
    Out[7]: 
         A   B   C   D
     a   1   4   4   4
     b   4   5   5   5
     c   3   6   6   6
     d   8   7   7   7
```

Second.one like this:

```
      Out[8]: 
     T1  T2  C2  D2   S2.   
  a  A4  B4  C4  D4.   A.
  a  ..............    B.
  a  ..............    C
  a  ..............    D
  b  A5  B5  C5  D5.   A
  b ...............    B
  ..
  ..     
  c  A6  B6  C6  D6.   A
  ...
  ...     
  d  A7  B7  C7  D7.   A
  d  ...............   B
  ...
```

I'm looking to do the following:

```
           Out[8]: 
          T1  T2  C2  D2   S2.     M
       a  A4  B4  C4  D4.   A      1
       a. A2. X4. C3. B8.   B      4
       a. S7. N4. R3. S7.   C      4
       .
       .
       .
       b  A5  B5  C5  D5.    A      4
       b. F4. F6.  C8. A5.    B      5
       ....
       .....
       c  A6  B6  C6  D6.    C.      6
       .....
       ......
       d  A7  B7  C7  D7.   D.     7
       ......
       .......
```

GOAL: Looking on values for the first column in the first and second dataframe(a,b,c,d) make a new column with values from first dataframe when the NAME COLUMN in the first df corresponds to the value ROW'S in column S2 of the second   . ITS NOT A DIAGONAL

Comment: Is my solution what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think need:

```
df = (df2.set_index('S2', append=True)
         .rename_axis((None, None))
         .join(df1.stack().rename('M'))
         .reset_index(level=1)
         .rename(columns={'level_1':'S2'}))
print (df)

  S2  T1  T2  C2   D2  M
a  A  A4  B4  C4  D4.  1
b  B  A5  B5  C5  D5.  5
c  C  A6  B6  C6  D6.  6
d  D  A7  B7  C7  D7.  7
```

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'( on line 3)

Comment: @Kameron - I cannot see `float`s values in your sample data. Something missing? Or real data are different and instead `a,b,c` or `A,B,C` are floats?

Comment: Sorry i was thinking it doesn't depend on format. Actually A,B,C,D are dates and numbers on rows of first df are prices.

Comment: If merge by `S2` and index in `df2` with index and columns names in `df1` is necessary all types are same. Here seems all types are strings. Btw, what is your pandas version? Because this kind of error I dont see before in `join`.

Comment: The column "M" are float numbers , maybe this is a problem?

Comment: @Kameron - I think no. Are data confidental?

Comment: Maybe because values a,b,c,d are repeated for every A,B,C,D in the,second column. Imagine that for every article(a,b,c,d ) in the store and every date A,B,C,D you have some variables(like T1,T2..) and a price for every date A,B,C,D which is collocated in the first dataframe.

Comment: @Kameron - Are data confidental?